# Bootstrap Datetimepicker Display Issue in Popup Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Bootstrap Datetimepicker Version - 4.15.35

I have a bootstrap datetimepicker in a modal form. It's working fine if it's at the top or middle of the modal window. If I place it at the bottom, the datetime picker open at the very top of the screen instead of below or next to the container.

**I add widgetParent option to it; it does not display the datetime control window now. I change the added a z-index of 999999, and it's still not displaying it.**

```
$('#StartDate').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false,
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm',
            widgetParent: '#StartDate',
            debug:true
        })

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu{
    z-index:99999999;
}
```

Here are two partial html codes generated for the same container except the location is changed.

**When the control is placed at the top or middle of the modal page:**

```
<div class="bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget dropdown-menu usetwentyfour 
bottom" style="display: block; top: 125px; bottom: auto; left: 165px; right: auto;">
```

**When the control is placed at the bottom of the modal page. It's almost the end of the modal, but there is enough space to display the control.**

```
<div class="bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget dropdown-menu top" 
style="display: block; top: auto; bottom: 543px; left: 165px; 
right: auto;"><ul class="list-unstyled">
```

Comment: Did you try  `widgetParent: 'body',`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were several solutions online, but they were not working for me. I had position relative added to the control's outer div. In addition, I had the widgetParent set to the control id. I played around with them and deleted my cache after every try. Finally, I removed the widgetParent option and added the position:relative to the outer div, and it works.

**//input**

```
    <div class="form-group" style="position:relative;">
      <label for="StartDate" class="sr-only">Start Date</label>
     <input type="text" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" class="form-control">
   </div>

$('#StartDate').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false,
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm',
            debug:true
        })
```

Comment: `style="position:relative;"` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

set in botstrap css input-group z-index auto